# How to force Chrome to use `box-sizing: content-box`? (2 nested DIVs, outer displayed as `table-cell`.)

Tags: css, google-chrome

## The goal

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4Ev4/) for the code below. **I want the `inner` div to be sized according to [the W3C specification of `box-sizing: content-box`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0), without modifying or removing any of the [non-empty CSS declarations](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#declaration), [selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#selector-syntax) or [HTML elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements).** (I want the current Chrome and Firefox versions, and Internet Explorer 11 to be supported.)

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer
{
    background:red;
    display:table-cell;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
}
#inner
{
    background:yellow;
    height:50%;
    padding:75px;
    width:50%;
}
```

Visual result:

[image: 300px by 300px all yellow box]

Box-model of the `inner` div:

[image: content: 150x150, padding: 75, border: 0, margin: 0]

## The problem

A buggy sizing method is used in Chrome (version: 35.0.1916.153 m, OS: Windows 7).

Visual result:

[image: top half yellow, bottom half red of 300px by 300px rectangle]

Box-model of the `inner` div:

[image: content: 150x0, padding: 75, border: 0, margin: 0]

## Additional info

- the vertical sizing of the `inner` div in Chrome is the same as [the W3C specification of `box-sizing: border-box`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0)
- setting `box-sizing: content-box` explicitly doesn't solve the problem
- both FF and IE11 works as expected, only Chrome not
- the sizing problem occurs only if `%` is used as the `inner` div's `height` unit, and the `outer` div is displayed as a `table-cell`
- a GIF illustrating the vertical sizing problem (no immediate growth):

[image: GIF illustrating the vertical sizing problem]

Comment: That's so odd.  If you set the top and bottom padding to 150px it works.  http://jsfiddle.net/p4Ev4/1/

Comment: What if you set the outer div as `display:table;` and the inner-div as `display:table-cell;`

Comment: @Smeegs: Yes, it seems like the "outer" height = maximum(height, sum(padding-top, padding-bottom)). Instead of sum(height, padding-top, padding-bottom). Strange.

Comment: @APAD1: I couldn't even set the height of the inner div then.

Comment: This does not seem to be a padding problem, but rather a _height_ problem – if you look at the computed values in Chrome dev tools, you see that the actual height is 0 – and if you change the height of `50%` to `150px` instead, it displays as expected, yellow all the way from top to bottom. A height in percentage is calculated based on the _containing block_ – according to http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#containing and http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#block-level the outer element with `display:table-cell` should form the containing block here, but Chrome seems to differ.

Comment: @CBroe: Thnks for the spec, it seems to be a bug then. I'll read [17.2 the CSS table model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display) and [the relevant part of the referenced HTML4 table model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6) to see if it's against the specs. Anyway, I believe it's both a padding and a height problem. I had seen the 0 height in dev tools, so I clarified the question earlier by mentioning the height as well. The padding still needs to be here, because the height gets nulled only if the vertical padding is not less than the height. Any ideas?

Comment: @CBroe I've read the specs and it's obviously a bug. I'll report it in an hour, but I still need to circumvent this problem until Google solves it. I'll try some typical hacks like position:relative, overflow:hidden, zoom:1 etc, but it seems to be a desperate struggle.

Comment: @CBroe Done. [See bug report here.](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/A9k4Q2nbTSM/w2SeOcuXq3sJ) Typical hacks didn't help, but setting the position:absolute solves the issue so I'll add it as an answer. (But in this case a wrapper div is needed to preserve the position settings.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The solution

Float the `outer` div; and [add a `wrapper` div displayed as `table`](http://jsfiddle.net/p4Ev4/26/), if [your original layout](http://jsfiddle.net/p4Ev4/24/) gets [messed up by floating](http://jsfiddle.net/p4Ev4/25/). [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4Ev4/19/) for the code below.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper
{
    display:table;
}
#outer
{
    background:red;
    display:table-cell;
    float:left;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
}
#inner
{
    background:yellow;
    height:50%;
    padding:75px;
    width:50%;
}
```

Visual result:

[image: 300px by 300px all yellow box]

Box-model of the `inner` div:

[image: content: 150x150, padding: 75, border: 0, margin: 0]

## Alternative solutions

Use [`#outer {position: absolute}`](http://jsfiddle.net/p4Ev4/13/), or [`#outer {position: fixed}`](http://jsfiddle.net/p4Ev4/14/), if the solution above (`#outer {float: left}`, or `#outer {float: right}`) doesn't suit your needs.

## Additional info

- This is [a known bug in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=285744). Click the link and add a comment, if you want it to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `display:table-cell;` use `display:table;` and set height 100%

For IE, just make a css code specific to its browser. Displays are funny between browsers

Or you can use APAD1's solution, much easier

Comment: The goal is not to make a 300px by 300px yellow rectangle, but to apply the vertical padding. If I set the height to 100%, the inner div is still only 300px high, not 450px as it should be. (I could achieve the same using one div, but it isn't what I'm looking for. Furthermore, it doesn't matter in your example if I use table or table-cell: I get the same result.)

Comment: As for APAD1's advice: I couldn't even set the height of the inner div then. Try setting the hight to 10px and you'll see.

Comment: So basically you're looking for the inner div to be 450px in height (including padding), 150px larger than the parent div, and for the yellow box to be placed in the middle of the red parent div at 150px total "yellow space"?

Comment: If you can help me understand what exactly you want, I'm sure I, or someone else could help you easier. I am still unsure what you're looking for

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the following part of your question:
>> at 150px total "yellow space" <<

But for the rest: yes, I want the inner to be 450px. But only in this certain example, so it wouldn't be a solution [to simply set #inner{height:450px}](http://jsfiddle.net/p4Ev4/3/). I want the real height to be the sum of the height and the vertical paddings.

Comment: Like a yellow box inside a red box, centered? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/BA5qk/ ?

Comment: It does sound like you want vertical centering. With the yellow sqaure exactly in the center, without a fixed height to allow for content to make it expand or contract?

Comment: Or you can set margin to 25% if the outer div expands?

Comment: @ctwheels I can center the div both horizontally and vertically, but I can't add a 150px padding-top and a 150px padding-bottom to the yellow div, if its height is 50%. See the updated question, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @MorganFeeney Centering works perfectly, so I didn't mention it in my question. The only problem is that I need to add a 150px padding-top and a 150px padding-bottom to the yellow div, while its height is 50%. But if I do it, the yellow box is only 150px instead of 450px* in Google Chrome. (* paddingTop+paddingBottom+height = 150px + 150px + 50% of parent height = 300px + 150px = 450px)

Comment: Here check out the new jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/BA5qk/2/, I'm not sure if this will help you. The padding shows up (remove it and you'll see). The div seems to be expanding downward because of the positioning.

Comment: I have to ask, why on earth do you want this to work? Anything in particular. You want the outer container to have a fixed height and width. Yet the inner div is to be larger, it doesn't make sense to do this. Unless you can give a reason that makes sense.

Maybe if you can explain what the ultimate goal is here?

Comment: @ctwheels This sizing method is perfect, this solution is almost what I want. But I still need the display:table-cell on the parent div, to center the inner div vertically when it becomes smaller than the outer. (And if I set it, the problem still persists.)

Comment: @MorganFeeney I send a bug report to Google, and then I'll update the question for you, to see the exact reason. Stay tuned! ;)

Comment: Cool, it's kind of interesting ;) I'd like to see this more in context with your gallery as a whole including using images etc.

Comment: Wait is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/BA5qk/3/ The yellow you see is the padding. If you remove the padding you'll see that the height is still 50%, however the height "disappears".

Comment: @ctwheels The height "disappearing" was the problem that I wanted to solve. (In other words the height property includes the padding, i.e. Chrome treats the height as if `box-sizing:border-box` was set, instead of the default `box-sizing:content-box`.) [See my solution for the result I was looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24409025/1293492), check the height in dev tools if you are interested. And thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @Tamas Bolvari I understand now what you wanted! Haha thanks, I'm sure this will help me in the future as well

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you think it is. You think that the structure has changed yet it is only appearance. Please see the screen shots. If you inspect in Firefox and IE you will see that the inner box is not filling the space of the parent div. You need to hover on the child div to see it's shape.

At this stage I don't believe this can be done, I have no idea why you want to do it either, it just seems pointless.

Correct me if I'm wrong ;)

[image: IE]

[image: FF]
Cheers

REVISED
++++++++++++++
OK there was more to this than originally thought. I have created a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mofeenster/p4Ev4/12/)** that demonstrates a suitable method (works in Chrome too).

The issue here is consistency cross-browser, yet retaining vertical alignment, and height. Browsers all behave differently therefore a more robust method is required. Using `width: 100%` & `height: 100%` plus `box-sizing: border box`, combined with `padding` solves the issue (unless I have it wrong).

Comment: The inner box IS filling the parent in FF & IE11. Talk about the screenshot of FF. The purple and the green area are both part of the inner div. The purple is the 75px wide [padding area](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#padding), the green is the 150px by 150px [content area](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#content). IE is the same, only the colors differ. Of course, it isn't pointless. :) I want a cross-browser solution, because it's fundamental to support Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer nowadays. This one is a critical part of an image gallery, so it's even more important. Do you agree?

Comment: I get it now, before there was no context so it confused everything.

Comment: I personally love using box-sizing: border-box as it makes things behave the way I want them to. Realistically you want the yellow div to be 100% in height, therefore why not set the height to 100% and add box-sizing: border-box to it then the padding will stay on the inside of the yellow div and won't add height.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what I was looking for is a solution that forces Chrome to use `box-sizing:content-box` instead of `box-sizing:border-box`. See my first reply for @ctwheels' answer. The same applies to your respone, except the last sentence.

Comment: Why do that, what is the benefit?

Comment: If an image is zoomed to 200%, I can simply set the height to 200%. (Instead of calculating the difference between the desired height and the height without paddings.) (`background-origin:content-box`, `background-size:cover`, `background:url(img.jpg) center no-repeat`)

Comment: The plot grows thicker. You don't want the image to be the size of it's container including the padding. So use margin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56286/discussion-between-morgan-feeney-and-tamas-bolvari).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final answer, after finally getting to the crux of what you wanted to achieve.

You stated you want people to be able to still click on the padding to access the image in your gallery, whilst retaining the required proportions.

You omitted quite a bit of important info, so finding out the point of your exercise was for an image gallery was crucial.

**I have to concede, you have answered your own question very well. *However here are some alternatives ;)***

Both examples retain your desired dimensions, including padding, vertical and horizontal alignment, and cross-browser consistency.

[Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/mofeenster/6mTKN/2/) (uses calc and no floating)

```
#wrapper
{
    display:table;
}
#outer
{
    background:red;
    display:table-cell;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;

}
#inner
{
    background:yellow url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg/300px-Hopetoun_falls.jpg) center no-repeat;
    background-origin:content-box;
    background-size:contain;
    height:100%;
    padding: 0 75px;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 150px);
    width:calc(100% - 150px);
    display: block;
}
```

**[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/mofeenster/fAZPc/)** doesn't quite fit your brief as it uses inline-block as opposed to table-cell, however they do behave alike in some ways.

```
#wrapper
{
    display:table;
}
#outer
{
    background:red;
    display:inline-block;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;

}
#inner
{
    background:yellow url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg/300px-Hopetoun_falls.jpg) center no-repeat;
    background-origin:content-box;
    background-size:contain;
    height:50%;
    padding:75px;
    width:50%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Again, I'm thankful for your helpfulness. As you can see in the edit history, what I wanted to do from the beginning is to "force Chrome using the correct `box-sizing` method: `content-box`". The other important requirement was that the "parent div" should be "displayed as a `table-cell`". Unfortunatelly, neither of your examples confrom to these 2 points. I think the "Additional info(...)" part of my question is not crucial nor important, but irrelevant and might be confusing for others. But I am always open to further inform others, especially if they need the "full picture" to help me.

Comment: Hi Tamas, Please see example 1 from my last answer. When you say "parent div" do you mean #outer? I cannot see any other parent div. You can see it is display: table-cell.

Comment: Hi Tamas, example 1 from my last answer does answer your brief, please have another look.

Comment: Hi Morgan. Yes, I mean `#outer`. Indeed, it's displayed as `table-cell`, so point 2 is OK. But check point 1 (`box-sizing: content-box`), and you'll see that Chrome unfortunatelly doesn't use the correct sizing method. E.g. if you set the `padding` of `#inner` to `75px`, it'll be `300px` high instead of `450px`. I'm just updating the question once again, I think it'll be super clear soon, I hope you'll agree.

Comment: Hi Tamas, now, at the end, after you have answered your own question, it is clear..